# Disable error reporting on Windows 2008 Server to avoid stalling the job queue?

Tags: windows-server-2008, job-control

I have a process running queue jobs and runs other processes to complete them. Occasionally the `.exe` it is running fails and this causes a crash report dialog to open (`WerFault.exe`). This causes all the other jobs on the queue to wait until someone clicks the button on the popup.

I've messed with the settings in *Control Panel > Problem Reports and Solutions*, but the best I can get is a popup with no options. I've also turned off the "Windows Error Reporting" service.

How do I disable `WerFault.exe`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say you've already "turned off the 'Windows Error Reporting' service", I'll propose going all the way in the other direction, i.e. letting it send all data without bothering you.

Have you seen [this MS Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709644%28WS.10%29.aspx) document mentioning the **"Send all data" setting** for Windows Error Reporting? From what I understand it is the only one **not requiring a pop-up**. However, you can't set it using the *Control Panel*, you **have to use `gpedit.msc`**.

- go to *Start/Run...*, type `gpedit.msc` to open the *Local Group Policy Editor*
- go to *Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Error Reporting\Consent*
- enable *Configure Default Consent* and set it to `Send all data`.
- verify that *Customize consent settings* enabled itself at the same time; if not `Enable` it now.

Unfortunately I can't try this here - I currently don't have a reliable way [to crash a Windows program](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/badapp.html) on my current machine without dragging out a compiler ;-).

**If all else fails...**

Have you considered replacing `WerFault.exe` with an `.exe` that does nothing, for example `true.exe` from [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)? Of course that would be a mayor step, but you could try as a last resort.